# Running more than one exe at the same time and dettect when all of them finishes JAVA

Tags: java

I don't think this is possible but I am trying to do it.

I am trying to execute exe files that the user introduces trough a scanner.

When they introduce them all, all exe start at the same time.

When they finish or gets closes, we get a message.

I already catch all the exe that the user introduces with this:

```
    String ruta = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(ruta);
        
        if(!ruta.equals("stop")){
            System.out.println("hola");
        }
        
  while(!ruta.equals("Stop") && !ruta.equals("stop")){
           
        nombreRuta.add(ruta);
     
               int length = ruta .length();
       //Convertimos la ruta para que sea legible y conseguimos el nombre del exe de la ruta
       ruta = ruta .replace("\\", "/");

     
       
       while(fin==false){

          if(  ruta.charAt((length-1)-contador)== '/' ){
              longitudexe=contador;
              fin=true;
          }
          else{
              contador++;
          }
           
       }
       
        nombreExe= ruta .substring(ruta .length()-longitudexe);
      exeRuta.add(nombreExe);
      
      
      
              System.out.print("Pon la ruta de otro exe o pon stop: ");
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
         ruta = input.nextLine();
    
  }     
   
 
       System.out.println( Arrays.toString(nombreRuta.toArray()));
```

It's in spanish but it captures the route and gets the exe. The problem is executing them all and getting the message.

I tried using this:

```
 String[] COMPOSED_COMMAND = {
        "C:\\Windows\\System32\\charmap.exe",
        "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe",
        "C:\\Windows\\System32\\colorcpl.exe",};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(COMPOSED_COMMAND);
```

doesn't work, only does the charmap.

I honestly don't know how to do it, I am working to find a solution for days.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you not simply execute `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` three times?

Comment: I tought about it, but how I can know if all the programs had finish?

Comment: The `Process` object has a method `isAlive()` you can check, or directly wait for its termination with `waitFor()`.

Comment: Alright, I follow your instructions and it worked! I just added a sout after all the exec() and works! Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

As Progman said, just execute Runtime.getRuntime().exec()  three times with waitFor() in each one.

```
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\charmap.exe").waitFor();
              Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\dvdplay.exe").waitFor();
              Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\colorcpl.exe").waitFor();

       System.out.println("Terminadas todas");
```

Comment: You should have a loop to exec all processes first, then `waitFor()`

Answer (score 0):

With Java8, you can use `ForkJoinPool` with Stream.

```
ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(5); //Any number more than 3

forkJoinPool.submit(()->

  Stream.of("C:\\Windows\\System32\\charmap.exe",
            "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe",
            "C:\\Windows\\System32\\colorcpl.exe")
    .parallel() //Run all at the same time
    .forEach( t ->
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(t).waitFor();
    )
)
```

Comment: And how I would know if all of them finishes?

Comment: @syzygysyzygy .waitFor() make sure that all processes will be blocked until it done. ForkJoinPool as the name suggests, it waits and join at the end. So, after forkJoinPoo.submit(..) every process will be done.